# Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:25

Tags: scala, playframework, smtp, playframework-2.0

When I try to send a mail from scala Playmework, I got following error,

```
[ERROR] [10/10/2013 13:31:16.263] [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-75] [TaskInvocation] Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:25
org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:25
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1242)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1267)
    at com.typesafe.plugin.CommonsMailer.send(MailerPlugin.scala:241)
    at com.typesafe.plugin.MailerBuilder$class.sendHtml(MailerPlugin.scala:204)
    at com.typesafe.plugin.CommonsMailer.sendHtml(MailerPlugin.scala:215)
    at models.SignUpProcess$$anonfun$models$SignUpProcess$$sendEmail$1.apply$mcV$sp(SignUpProcess.scala:261)
    at akka.actor.DefaultScheduler$$anon$8.run(Scheduler.scala:193)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:137)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1417)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:262)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:975)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1478)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104)
Caused by: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:319)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:118)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:188)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1232)
    ... 12 more
```

How to solve this error?

**SignUpProcess.scala**

```
private def sendEmail(subject: String, recipient: String, bodyString:Html) {

        import scala.concurrent.duration._
        import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits._

        Akka.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(1 seconds) {
          val mail = use[MailerPlugin].email
          mail.setSubject(subject)
          mail.addRecipient(recipient)
          mail.addFrom("innodeagcm@gmail.com")
          println(bodyString)


          mail.sendHtml(bodyString.toString)
        }
}
```

**application.conf**

```
smtp.host = smtp.gmail.com
smtp.port = 465
smtp.ssl = true
smtp.tls = no
smtp.user = "companymail@gmail.com"
smtp.password = "mypassword"
```

Comment: If you are getting this error despite trying every known solution, make sure you you don't have an antivirus running on your computer. After uninstalling Avast, everything worked smoothly.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**1.**  Here is a working configuration for **GMail** :

```
smtp.host=smtp.gmail.com
smtp.port=587
smtp.ssl=yes
smtp.user="me@gmail.com"
smtp.password="myPassword"
```

You must use **port 587** (and so activate **SSL**)

**2.** Also ensure that **Two factor authentication is not activated** (otherwise you must generate a new application password)

**3.** Another cause of connection fail : it can be seemed like a **suspect connection**.

So check mails received from google on your account to ensure the connection has not been blocked by google (happens if play is hosted in another country than the one you are used to connect manually)

Comment: No this also not works. Now my Play framework application run on my VPS(Virtual private server).Still I didn't have SSL certificate for my VPS.Shall I want to add SSL certificate to access the gmail SMTP with SSL? or need to configure anything in my VPS?

Comment: @Ram There is a workaround to use smtp.gmail.com without SSL
([link google group topic](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/G6rE7PFX4rM))



        But seems more complicated than add SSL on a server.

Answer (score 11):

smtp:port=587 didn't work for me. but port 465 worked for me.

And turn on google less secure app setting[image]

```
smtp.host=smtp.gmail.com
smtp.port=465
smtp.ssl=true
```

Comment: This was helpful.

Answer (score 7):

You should first enable the  access in Google for less secure App as shown in the above answer. Now Change the port to 465 and set ssl=true. Or you can set port=587 and tls=true. This is because port 465 is for SSL and port 587 is for TLS according to the official documentations.

> port=465 
> ssl=true

**Note that port=587 with ssl=true won't work

Answer (score 0):

If you feel all settings are correct, but still getting this message; I'd suggest to look at the attachments. I was sending a **.JAR** file which gmail servers won't allow you to attach and hence it was rejecting my email. I had to rename the file to **.JARA** to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I've read all comment to here and I've had success. For this reason: this is my code that It could work perfectly.

```
smtp.host=smtp.gmail.com
smtp.port=465
smtp.ssl=true
smtp.auth=true
smtp.user="xxxxxx@gmail.com"
smtp.password=xxxxxxx
```